# Input type 'tel' recognize as email type - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, email, autocomplete

I created Angular Form and it has few fields with two telephone fileds. The case is one of the telephone-type input field recognized as email type.

Here is my implementation,

1. **component.html**

   ```
   <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-group">
       <!--some controllers here -->
       <div class="full-name-inputs row">
            <input type="email" nbInput fullWidth shape="rectangle" formControlName="email" 
                        placeholder="Email*" [email]="true" required
                        [ngClass]="{'border border-danger': form.get('email').errors && 
                        form.get('email').touched}"/>
            <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('required') && 
                        form.get('email').touched">
                            Email is required.
            </small>
            <small class="text-danger"
               *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('email')
                 && form.get('email').touched">
                     Enter valid email address.
           </small>
       </div>
       <!-- some controllers here -->
       <div class="full-name-inputs">
           <input type="tel" nbInput fullWidth formControlName="mobileContact" 
                             placeholder="Mobile contact"/>
           <input type="tel" nbInput fullWidth formControlName="officeContact" 
                    placeholder="Office contact" autocomplete="doNotAutoComplete"/>
       </div>
   ```
2. **component.ts**

   ```
    export class ProfileDialogComponent implements OnInit {
        form: FormGroup;
        // constructor

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5), Validators.minLength(2)]],
                firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12), 
                                           Validators.minLength(3)]],
                lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12), 
                     Validators.minLength(3)]],
                email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
                designation: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]],
                mobileContact: [''],
                officeContact: [''],
                remark: [''],
                password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), 
                            Validators.pattern(this.pattern)]],
                 passwordConfirm: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
            }, {
                  validators: this.password.bind(this),
            });
        }
    }
   ```

**Following is the output:**

[image: Auto completed image]

[image: autofill suggest image]

**Inspect element code for *tel* field:**

```
<input _ngcontent-vkp-c480="" type="tel" nbinput="" fullwidth="" formcontrolname="officeContact" 
placeholder="Office contact" autocomplete="doNotAutoComplete" ng-reflect-full-width="" ng-reflect- 
name="officeContact" class="input-full-width size-medium status-basic shape-rectangle ng-valid nb- 
transition ng-dirty ng-touched">
```

**Tested :**

- Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141
- Microsoft Edge Version 87.0.664.75

Anyone can suggest the issue?

Comment: Try to ad the "pattern" attribute to the tel field. This allows you to specify a regular expression that the browser will use to validate the value of the tel field. 
see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Comment: @Node_Ninja not working. same output